# Flutter integration tests for iOS on Firebase?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-test-lab

Is it possible to run Flutter integration tests on Firebase? There seems to be conflicting info on this - some sources say its possible, but on [the documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test#firebase-test-lab), the iOS section seems to only be for testing on your own device.

Firebase asks for an XCT test package to be uploaded. How can it be obtained / created for a Flutter project?

Comment: i dont understand what you want exactly ?

Comment: @JanviPate > Firebase asks for an XCT test package to be uploaded. How can it be obtained / created for a Flutter project?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write Flutter integration tests for iOS on Firebase Test Lab. Even with **Dart code** and **not** Swift code. You need to use the `integration_test` package. You will find in the Flutter documentation how to set up the `integration_test` package: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/integration-tests

Your test will look like something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import '../lib/main.dart' as app;

// How to run?
// flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/app_test.dart

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Currently, we can't setup intergration tests, because there is a issue with integraiton test package +
  // localization.
  //
  // See this ticket for information: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84053
  testWidgets('full app test', (tester) async {
    app.main();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    // Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

To be able to run this test as a XCTest (this is what Firebase Test Lab needs), you need to some extra steps:

Open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode. Create a test target if you
do not already have one via `File > New > Target...` and select `Unit Testing Bundle`.
Change the `Product Name` to `RunnerTests`. Make sure `Target to be Tested` is set to `Runner` and language is set to `Objective-C`.
Select `Finish`.
Make sure that the **iOS Deployment Target** of `RunnerTests` within the **Build Settings** section is the same as `Runner`.

Add the new test target to `ios/Podfile` by embedding in the existing `Runner` target.

```rb
target 'Runner' do
  # Do not change existing lines.
  ...

  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

To build `integration_test/foo_test.dart` from the command line, run:

```sh
flutter build ios --config-only integration_test/foo_test.dart
```

In Xcode, add a test file called `RunnerTests.m` (or any name of your choice) to the new target and
replace the file:

```objectivec
@import XCTest;
@import integration_test;

INTEGRATION_TEST_IOS_RUNNER(RunnerTests)
```

Run `Product > Test` to run the integration tests on your selected device.

To deploy it to Firebase Test Lab you can follow these steps:

Execute this script at the root of your Flutter app:

```sh
output="../build/ios_integ"
product="build/ios_integ/Build/Products"
dev_target="14.3"

# Pass --simulator if building for the simulator.
flutter build ios integration_test/foo_test.dart --release

pushd ios
xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -config Flutter/Release.xcconfig -derivedDataPath $output -sdk iphoneos build-for-testing
popd

pushd $product
zip -r "ios_tests.zip" "Release-iphoneos" "Runner_iphoneos$dev_target-arm64.xctestrun"
popd
```

You can verify locally that your tests are successful by running the following command:

```sh
xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun "build/ios_integ/Build/Products/Runner_iphoneos14.3-arm64.xctestrun" -destination id=<YOUR_DEVICE_ID>
```

Once everything is ok, you can upload the resulting zip to Firebase Test Lab (change the model with your values):

```sh
gcloud firebase test ios run --test "build/ios_integ/ios_tests.zip" --device model=iphone11pro,version=14.1,locale=fr_FR,orientation=portrait
```

Note: I copied to the needed extra for iOS device tests steps from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test#ios-device-testing (credits to the Flutter team ❤️)

If you want to run these tests on Android Firebase Test Lab, you need also to do some extra steps. You will find these steps under: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test#android-device-testing. I can also recommend to check out this video, where [Reso Coder](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSIvrn68cUk8CS8MbtBmBkA) explained and showed every little step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izajHHFSa8o

Comment: Execution of test on firebase test lab fails with error:  The XCTest zip file was malformed. The zip did not contain a single .xctestrun file and the contents of the DerivedData/Build/Products directory..

Answer (score 2):

First of all open your ios Module in Xcode as ss below.

[image]

Now you are free to write cool XCode UI tests with Swift. For example I am dropping here a Firebase Login test for your app maybe you wish to use.

```
import XCTest
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginTestUITests: XCTestCase {

    var app: XCUIApplication!
    
    func testLogin() {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        wait(for: 2)
        passLogin()
        wait(for: 5)
     // after your login you can add some methods here according to your app flow
    }
}

extension LoginTestUITests {

func passLogin() {
    
    //put your logic here        
    
}
// this is a pretty cool extension waiting according to input for a while coming the data from backend etc.
extension XCTestCase {
    func wait(for duration: TimeInterval) {
        let waitExpectation = expectation(description: "Waiting")
        
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + duration
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            waitExpectation.fulfill()
        }
        // I use a buffer here to avoid flakiness with Timer on CI
        waitForExpectations(timeout: duration + 0.5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also there is a nice sample case which explain how to write for swiping test on different screens. https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/getting-started-with-xcode-ui-testing-in-swift/

Comment: So there's no way to write the tests in Dart / Flutter and have those be used? I'm guessing these swift tests can't be used to interact with buttons / UI elements created using Flutter

Comment: I think you need to implement Swifty codes.

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode project (by default, it's ios/Runner.xcodeproj). Create a test target (navigating File > New > Target... and set up the values) and a test file RunnerTests.m and change the code. You can change RunnerTests.m to the name of your choice.

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <integration_test/IntegrationTestIosTest.h>

INTEGRATION_TEST_IOS_RUNNER(RunnerTests)
```

Comment: This is the same info as in the docs but this doesn't explain: 1) Will this run my flutter integration tests? 2) How do I obtain the XCT package that Firebase asks for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Xcode to do it. If you are using Android first open iOS module in Xcode

[image]

Then in Xcode open the Test navigator (Command-6) and add new test target:
[image]

Now we have two targets for Unit and UI test in our Flutter project

[image]

Our project is ready for test and we can check it run Product ▸ Test or Command-U in Xcode:

[image]

Then Firebase Test Lab:

- iOS: Write XCTests, then build and package your app for upload.

Just create application package using Xcode Product > Archive selecting real device as a target.

Comment: Do I have to write the tests in Swift? Or is there a way to write my tests in Dart using flutter code, and have those hooked to XCTests somehow which Firebase can run?

Comment: Looks like need to write in Swift, did not find anything for Dart but it should not be very difficult. There is the link that should help https://www.raywenderlich.com/960290-ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial , cheers