# How to declare type of anonymous functions in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I need a function passed into a method which takes a String and turns it into a double:

```
void strToDouble(String input, Function converter) {
  print('As a double, $input is ${converter(input)}`);
}
```

(Obviously toy example)

How can I declare the type of `converter` as a function that turns a `String` to double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To declare your `converter` callback as a `Function` that takes a `String` and returns a `double`, its type should be: `double Function(String)`.  Therefore your `strToDouble` function would be:

```dart
void strToDouble(String input, double Function(String) converter) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042050/flutter-integration-tests-for-ios-on-firebase please

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typedef`

```
typedef double ConvertStringToDouble(String input);

void main() {
  ConvertStringToDouble cs = (String input){
    return double.parse(input);
  };
  
  strToDouble("29.0", cs);
}
void strToDouble(String input, ConvertStringToDouble converter) {
  print("As a double, $input is ${converter(input)}");
}
```

Comment: Can I declare it `cs` w/ lambda syntax instead in main?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Using a `typedef` isn't strictly necessary (although it can be more readable).  You also should [prefer the modern `typedef` syntax](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#dont-use-the-legacy-typedef-syntax) which would make it clearer how to specify the type without using a `typedef`: `typedef ConvertStringToDouble = double Function(String input);`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function you want to call to get the output as double by passing the string and the converter function:

```
  dynamic dynamicConverter (String input, double Function(dynamic input) convert){
    return convert.call(input);
  }
```

You will have to use it like below:

```
   double output = dynamicConverter("120", (input) {
      return double.parse(input);
    });
```